# Callback for generic type functions

Tags: c#, .net, generics, callback

I'm trying to save a reference to a generic method of an object ("callback"). Then, in another generic method ("test"), I want to be able to call that saved callback method ("callback") with the same generic type parameter that was passed to test.

Here's some pseudo-code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
public class A
{

    public A()
    {
        b = new B();
        b.setCallback(this.callback);   // should be a reference to the callback<T>() function of this class
        b.test<String>();   // this should now call: this.callback<String>()
    }

    public bool callback<T>()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class B
{
    Delegate _callback;

    public void setCallback(Delegate d)
    {
        this._callback = d; 
    }

    public bool test<T>()
    {
        return this._callback<T>();
    }
}
```

So far, I tried with delegates, Action<>s and Func<>s, but couldn't find a way to solve this while keeping the type T dynamic (then again, I am not very experienced with delegates etc.). I do not want to make the entire class a generic type, just the respective methods.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Callback should return boolean? How string related to your callback? If you are going to pass string parameter to callback function then where do you get it from?

Comment: What's wrong with class B having a type parameter?

Comment: Why are you using generics at all when your callback appears to take no arguments and return a bool?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do since your callback does not seem to make use of any generic parameters, but if you don't want to make `B` generic you can do:

```
public class B
{
    Delegate _callback;

    public void setCallback<T>(Func<T> d)
    {
        this._callback = d; 
    }

    public bool test<T>()
    {
        var f = this._callback as Func<T>;
        if(f == null) throw new ArgumentException();
        T ignored = this._callback();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will indeed work but there won't be any type validation occuring at compile time. Maybe the OP is okay with this but if he is I'd question why he's even using generics at all. Still, in current context, it's a valuable answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would want two methods in a class to be both *safely* (as in "no runtime casting needed") bound to the same, unconstrained parameter type, yet without declaring that parameter type at the class level.

If that's what you are looking for then **the real answer** to your question **is that it's impossible**. You will *not* be able to enforce your callback parameter to be matching the type parameter of your `Test` method at compile-time, unless they're both bound to the same class-level type parameter *or* constrained to some base type.

What you *can* do however is passing the callback parameter to the `Test` method:

```
public T Test<T>(Func<T> callback)
{
    return callback.Invoke();
}
```

Note that since your code is pseudo, I took the liberty to change `Test` method's return type to the dynamic type here. I believe that was your original intention. If not please provide additional details.